# При скролле контент налезает на панель навигации, как исправить?

Tags: frontend

Есть сайт https://www.akustik-studio.ru.
Когда браузер открыт на весь экран- панель навигации отображается в одну строку и всё корректно. Когда браузер открыт не на весь экран, две кнопки из панели навигации переходят на вторую строку и при скролле контент налезает на эти кнопки. Как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну какие у вас варианты.

1. Задать списку меню фикс высоту шапки и скрыть через overflow. Тогда они не будут падать и не будут видны
2. Переделать меню на флексы, с использованием flex-wrap:nowrap, а так же горизонтальной прокруткой.
3. Сдвинуть брейкпоинт с 991px который меняет всю картину меню на 1200px.
4. На этом же брейкпоинте меняется ширина контейнера. Можно ее изменить, можно изменить отступы у менюшек в промежутке с 991-1200
5. Так же можно поменять размерность сетки тут: `col-8 col-md-1 col-xl-3` у меню: `col-4 col-md-11 col-xl-9` и нужно будет еще для лого применить `object-fit: contain;`, но я бы заменил на более мелкое лого в принципе